# Переименовать заголовок окна

Tags: c#

Возможно ли силами C# отловить заголовок окна стороннего ПО и переименовать его на время сессии. Например найти процесс calculator.exe отловить заголовок "Калькулятор" и переименовать его в "Тест"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сначала находим окно и его значение hWnd по названию[(отсюда)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547639/return-window-handle-by-its-name-title/13547659#13547659):

```
  IntPtr hWnd = IntPtr.Zero;
foreach (Process pList in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   if (pList.MainWindowTitle.Contains(wName))
  {
      hWnd = pList.MainWindowHandle;
  }
}
return hWnd; //Should contain the handle but may be zero if the title doesn't match
```

Затем устанавливаем значение окна [(отсюда)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15988917/how-can-i-set-the-window-text-of-an-application-using-net-process-start):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, string text);
```

Comment: Спасибо! Подскажите а возможно сделать из этого DLL привязать в кинуть в папку к программе и что она сама при запуске переименовывала?

Comment: Не понял вопроса, уточните что вы имеете в виду. DLL - это динамическая библиотека, её используют так же как и любую другую библиотеку - подключают в проекте и вызывают функции или используют классы, которые в ней находятся.

Comment: wName - имя окна которое необходимо переименовать?

Comment: Да, это текст в названии искомого окна